# How do I cast the result of a UNION in SQLite?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have a view defined as the union of a BLOB column in multiple tables. The problem is that that result is being cast to TEXT whereas it should be BLOB. Therefore, how do I cast the result of the UNION in the view definition to a BLOB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a subquery.

```
SELECT CAST( column1 AS BLOB )
FROM (
    SELECT column1
    FROM table1

    UNION

    SELECT column1
    FROM table2
);
```

This will allow you to cast the resulting data.